# GET call using HttpsURLConnection to fetch an image

Tags: java, rest

I am calling some external web services and I am able to successfully fetch the JSON response with the following code :

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
URL obj = new URL(rest_url); 
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (con.getInputStream())));

while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(output);
}
```

Now, I have a external web service which returns an image.

How do I make a GET call using HttpsURLConnection to fetch this image?

Comment: What is the problem with the external web service? Could you please post the exact source code that you have tried to use to access the service?

Comment: Hi , There is no problem with the web service . It now returns an PNG IMAGE instead of text . So I just want to know if I need to do anything different in my code to fetch the IMAGE.

Comment: Hello! If the service exposes its resources over HTTPS and does not require any authentication, authorisation, etc., then the provided source code should work just fine. But the code reads the data into a string (`StringBuffer`). Why not read the data as a byte array? What is the final purpose of the code? To fetch the file and save it to the local file system?

Comment: just write `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file_path.png");` and write contents to file `writer.write(response.toString());` and close it `writer.close();` and done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void fetchImage() throws IOException{
                 URL obj = new URL(rest_url); 
                 HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

                 con.setDoOutput(true);
                 con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                 //specify your image file destination path
                 File destinationFile=new File("/destinationPath");
                 FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
                 InputStream inputStream=con.getInputStream();
                 //start stream copy using a buffersize. here i am using a beffer size=1024
                 copyStream(inputStream, outputStream, 1024);
                 outputStream.close();
                 inputStream.close();
            }   

    /*copy an inputStream to an OutputStream using a specific buffer size*/
    public static OutputStream copyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os, int buffer_size) throws IOException{


                            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];

                            for (; ; ) {
                                // Read byte from input stream

                                int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                                if (count == -1)
                                    break;

                                // Write byte to output stream
                                os.write(bytes, 0, count);
                            }

                        return os;
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The answer given by Toukea Tatsi worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to save image from url.

```
public static void saveImageFromURL(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Hope it'll help.